# No able to save fabric canvas as image using FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs, filesaver.js

I have included Fabric.js and Filesaver.js in my code but still
I am getting "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported." error whenever I am trying to save the fabric canvas.

I referred: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng8OJ6a-wQY

Is there a way I could be able to save the canvas to a shared directory location?

```js
//-----------------------------Getting hold of Canvas---------------------------------------

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight * 0.75);
canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth * 0.75);
drawBackground();

//--------------------------Image Rendering-------------------------------------------------

function drawBackground() {
  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg', function(img) {
  img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.scaleToWidth(window.innerWidth * 0.75);
    img.scaleToHeight(window.innerHeight * 0.75);
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
}

//------------------------Rectangle---------------------------------------------------------

window.addRect = function() {
  var box = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    stroke: 'red',
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,.4)',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  });
  box.hasRotatingPoint = false;
  canvas.add(box);
}

//---------------------Circle-------------------------------------------------------------

window.addCircle = function() {
  var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    radius: 50,
    stroke: 'green',
    fill: 'transparent',
  });
  circle.hasRotatingPoint = false;
  canvas.add(circle);
}

//-----------------------Line Arrow-----------------------------------------------------

window.addArrow = function() {
  var arrowbox = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    stroke: 'red',
    fill: 'red',
    width: 1,
    height: 50,
  });

var arrowtriangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 10, height: 10, fill: 'red', left: -4, top: -10
});

var arrowgroup = new fabric.Group([ arrowbox, arrowtriangle ], {
  left: 150,
  top: 100,
  angle: 90
});

canvas.add(arrowgroup);
}

//-----------------------Save Canvas---------------------------------------------------------

window.saveCanvas = function(){
 canvas.getElement().toBlob(function(blob){
 saveAs(blob, annotation.png);
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
<button onClick="addCircle()">Circle</button>
<button onClick="addRect()">Box</button>
<button onClick="addArrow()">Arrow</button>
<button onClick="saveCanvas()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same problem using fabric js. My current solution is encode the canvas element to base64 string using [`toDataUrl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) and send it to server side code to decode it again, then write it as image file. I am using PHP on the server side

Comment: Are you still facing issues with the approach you mentioned above?

Comment: I am not sure how it could be done in java though, but let me try it out. Would it be possible for you to share your php code for this issue?

Comment: here is my [code](https://gist.github.com/azhry/cca745c903f5ad58991eb0280992bde0)

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it. Will keep here updated, when I am able to pull this up.